Construct a simple iterative C program to generate a given character sequence
I’ve been reading about PRNGs like LCGs and their derivatives. This got me thinking; what if I wanted to go backwards, coming up with a recurrence relation given a particular sequence of numbers.  Say I had a given sequence of letters. To keep it simple a is encoded as 0, b as 1, and so on with z encoded as 25. I want to construct a minimal C program that, let’s say, keeps three 32 bit integers for state and another to output the current character of the sequence, and when run generates at each iteration the next character in the sequence. Say the sequence is “helloworld”

(If 42 is the answer, what has been the question?)(Given the Latin alphabet, mapping a:0 … z:25 isn't that simple.)

So you want a PRNG with a period of 10, that always generates values in the order 7,4,11,11,14,16,14,50,11,3,7,4,11,11,14,16,14... This sounds like a very hard problem, in general. I imagine if your phrase were 100 characters rather than 10, the problem may well be intractable.
